Sum of every $k$th binomial coefficients over upperindex
From the Hockey-Stick Identity, we have for $n\geq r \geq 0$:
$$\sum_{i=r}^{n} \binom{i}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}.$$
Now, I am wondering whether an identity exists for any fixed ( $k > 0$ ):
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{r + ki }{r} =\, ?$$
Does such an identity exist? Or, are there ways to provide an approximation for the term?
